# Simple explanation of the dynamical mean field theory (DMFT)?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, many-body, mean-field-theory

Can someone give me a good reference article or book, that explains the dynamical mean field theory (DMFT) in a simplest possible manner?

I've read quite a lot about the DMFT (and used it), but somehow I still feel I do not fully understand it yet.

Comment: I've given an answer to your other question, with essentially the same answer as I'd give here. I'll add that I found the best DMFT resource is the 90s-era review: Georges, Antoine, et al. "Dynamical mean-field theory of strongly correlated fermion systems and the limit of infinite dimensions." Reviews of Modern Physics 68.1 (1996): 13.